# <SOCKET>>::tuple': no overloaded function takes 3 arguments. in Qt visual studio 2019

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2019, qt-creator

I have made a client and a server. In server I have done multi threading. Now I am making a UI for my server program using Qt in visual studio 2019. But now here in my server code after running it when I run my client the server program gives me an exception " cannot send events to objects owned by another thread". I want to make a different thread in server for handling all the clients and my main thread will handle the GUI since the GUI freezes so I need a different thread to handle my clients. I have attached my server and client code below .  can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Based on the error message, it seems like your actual code says "tuple", not "thread".

Comment: @molbdnilo this is the error I am getting while making a thread.

Comment: Yes, but the error message mentions "tuple", which is very odd. Did you copy and paste the code or retype it? Are you absolutely sure that the code in the question is the code that the error message refers to? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @molbdnilo yes I've just cop pasted the code

Comment: also, I have added my code in the question of server.cpp file

Comment: Show the code of `server2` class. For me it is not copyable, so passing it by value `ser` failed. To resolve it pass `ser` by reference `&ser` instead. `th1(&server2::handle_gui,&ser,std::ref(listening));`

Comment: @rafix07 I have edited my question and I have attached all the code for server and client both. here I aam making a ui for server using Qt and my client is simply a cpp program. I will make the ui for the client afterwards.

Comment: QObject is not copyable. QObject is base class of QMainWindow, so QMainWindow is not copyable, in result `server2` instances also cannot be copied. You create `thread` taking server by value - it is not possible. You can pass server by pointer or reference to avoid copying object.

Comment: @rafix07 you mean like this ? std::thread th1(&server2::handle_gui,&server2,std::ref(listening));

Comment: @rafix07 instead of `ser` object of `server2` class I have directly passed the reference of `server2` class but it is giving me an error "no instance of constructor matches the argument"